# Xcode UI Testing - Multiple UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

If we have multiple UITableViews, how do we specify which one in our XCUITests?

```
XCUIApplication().tables.cells.count
```

returns all the cells.  How can we choose which table to limit the count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiate your table views with an accessibility identifier.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let firstTableView: UITableView!
    let secondTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        firstTableView.accessibilityIdentifier = "First Table"
        secondTableView.accessibilityIdentifier = "Second Table"
    }
}
```

Then you can reference one of the tables directly in your UI tests.

```
XCUIApplication().tables["First Table"].cells.count
```

Comment: Does that have to be done in viewDidLoad or can we do that in the storyboards too?

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious but I do not see how to set the accessibility identifier on the table view in the storyboard.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Looks like it doesn't show up for `UITableView`s. Not sure why. Bug report?

Comment: accessibilityIdentifier seems to be only for views